# Centralizar componentes

Tags: jsf, primefaces

O print abaixo é da confirmação de um registro do meu datatable, o popup é aberto quando se clica no botão de excluir o registro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código deste dialog é o seguinte:

```
<p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-trash" action="#{geracaomb.excluir(linha)}" ajax="true" process="@this" update="pesquisa">
    <p:confirm header="#{msg['cabecalho.apagar.registro']}" message="#{msg['apagar.registro']}" icon="ui-icon-alert" />
    </p:commandButton>
    <p:confirmDialog global="true" showEffect="exploud" hideEffect="fade">
    <p:commandButton value="Sim" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-check"/>
    <p:commandButton value="Não" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="ui-icon-close"/>
    </p:confirmDialog>
```

Eu quero colocar o título (CONFIRMAÇÃO) e os 2 botões (Sim e Não) centralizados, como eu faço isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Método 1 (sem alterar o CSS):**

Não sei se é possível centralizar o título sem mexer no CSS, mas os botões dá pra fazer:

```
<p:confirmDialog global="true" showEffect="explode" hideEffect="fade">
    <div style="display:flex;justify-content:center;align-items:center;">
        <p:commandButton value="Sim" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-check"/>
        <p:commandButton value="Não" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="ui-icon-close"/>
    </div>
</p:confirmDialog>
```

**Método 2 (customizando o CSS do Primefaces):**

Existem várias maneiras de customizar o CSS, abaixo segue um exemplo de customização de CSS na própria página, usando a tag `<style>`. Nesse caso, não haveria nenhuma alteração no seu ConfirmDialog, todas as alterações seriam no CSS:

```
<style>
.ui-dialog-title {
    width: 88%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-right: 0 !important;
}
.ui-dialog-buttonpane {
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
}
</style>
```

[image: Exemplo do ConfirmDialog]

Talvez seja necessário ajustar os valores do `width` e `margin-right` para o seu projeto, mas só testando. Segue a lista dos demais Style Class do ConfirmDialog:

- **.ui-dialog** Container element of dialog
- **.ui-dialog-titlebar** Title bar
- **.ui-dialog-title** Header text
- **.ui-dialog-titlebar-close** Close icon
- **.ui-dialog-content** Dialog body
- **.ui-dialog-buttonpane** Footer button panel

Comment: Você sabe como posso fazer pra aplicar as alterações para que meu projeto pegue as novas alterações ?

Comment: Editei a resposta para inclusão do método 2, usando o CSS para alterar o ConfirmDialog. Faça o teste no seu projeto.

Comment: Show, muito obrigado.